# ¿Se pueden intercambiar de lugar un video con un hola mundo en html?

Tags: html, video

Es una tarea que tengo, como soy nuevo en lo que es la programación se me hace un poco raro eso. Nos dijo el profesor que el vídeo por ejemplo tiene que estar a la izquierda y el hola mundo a la derecha y que al hacer algún clic cambien de lugar. Es posible eso? me dejo en dudas xq después de explicarlo hizo una mueca, lo primero que se paso por la cabeza es que es una prueba

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de lo que estas haciendo para poder ayudarte de mejor manera

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 
 <head>
  
  <title> 2do Parcial </title>
 
 <style type="text/css">
    h1{
    color: #e2e2e2;
    }
    </style>
 
 </head>

<body background="Fondo.jpg">
 <h1>
    <DIV ALIGN=right>Hola Mundo</DIV>
 </h1>
 <video src="Video.mp4"></video>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 
 </script>

</body>

</html>

Comment: eso es lo que hice. no se como ponen el algoritmo jaja

Comment: Tal y como está redactada ahora, esta pregunta es básicamente un "hagan mi tarea por mí". Deberías añadir información sobre lo que hayas intentado (no sólo la plantilla, sino también el JS), y de las dificultades que te estés encontrando. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Mi profesor no nos enseña nada. Dice que programar es como la tabla del 1, que eso no se enseña en la escuela. Solo pregunte si era posible no que me resuelvan todo

Comment: La vez pasada pregunte algo igual que ahora, y el algoritmo que me mandaron no lo use xq no lo entiendo y es bastante avanzado para lo que es mi nivel.

Answer (score 0):

Si, es posible, yo hice algo parecido, lo que hay que hacer es poner el vídeo en un div y el hola mundo otro div y un boton o link, un css para posicionar las divs, el boton o link qllama a una funcion en javascripts, y esa funcion mueve las divs.

Comment: Te recomiendo leas https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer para conocer como escribir una buena respuesta. Si quieres dar una idea que sirva de directriz en la resolución del problema, escribe un comentario sobre dicha pregunta.

Comment: Gracias, soy nuevo en stackoverfow y eso me ayudo bastante ;).

Answer (score 0):

Habrá muchas manera de hacer eso.

Aquí hay dos formas de hacerlo.

El código hace lo mismo, tanto en Javascript puro como en jQuery.

### Forma 1:

```js
/*jQuery*/
$('#checkJq').change(function () {

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#div2').insertBefore($('#div1'));
    } else {
        $('#div1').insertBefore($('#div2'));
    }

});

/*JS*/

var checkJs = document.getElementById("checkJS");

  checkJs.onclick = function() { 
      var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
      var parentDiv = div1.parentNode;
      var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");


      if (this.checked){
        parentDiv.insertBefore(div2, div1);  
      }else{
        parentDiv.insertBefore(div1, div2);  
    } 
  };
```

```css
.content {
  width: 520px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div1 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 315px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 315px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Cambiar con jQuery<input id="checkJq" type="checkbox" value="0" />
Cambiar con Javascript<input id="checkJS" type="checkbox" value="0" />


<div class="content">
  <div id="div1" class="div1">No soy un vídeo</div>
  <div id="div2" class="div2"><iframe width="260" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NvVpAxQuBg4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

---

### Forma 2:

```js
function cambiarJS() {

  var strDiv1 = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML;
  var strDiv2 = document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML;

  document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = strDiv2;
  document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = strDiv1;
}

function cambiarJQ() {
  var strDiv1 = $("#div1").html();
  var strDiv2 = $("#div2").html();

  $("#div1").html(strDiv2);
  $("#div2").html(strDiv1);
}
```

```css
.content {
  width: 520px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div1 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 315px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 315px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnJS" onclick="cambiarJS()">Cambia usando JavaScript</button>
<button id="btnJQ" onclick="cambiarJS()">Cambia usando jQuery</button>
<div class="content">
  <div id="div1" class="div1">No soy un vídeo</div>
  <div id="div2" class="div2"><iframe width="260" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NvVpAxQuBg4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando el elemento que se mueve es el video (de derecha a izquierda), éste deja de reproducirse porque lo que se hace es que se quita del DOM y se vuelve a añadir. Se podría conseguir una mejor experiencia de usuario  añadiendo una clase al .content y con CSS hacer que los divs floten a la derecha en lugar de la izquierda. De ese modo, el DOM no cambiaría, sólo la visualización en el navegador y el video no se cortaría. Claro que todo esto es teórico y no un caso real, por lo que la experiencia de usuario tampoco importa mucho.